# ACTION_ASSIST intent on Marshmallow (Android 6.0)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-6.0-marshmallow

Is there a way to use the `ACTION_ASSIST` (Google now) intent on Android 6.0?

I think this might have changed with the now on tap feature - but perhaps (hopefully) there is still a way to hook into this.

Comment: What do you mean by "use the ASSIST ( google now ) intent"? Do you mean implement an assistant to replace Now On Tap?

Comment: No just use it as a launch entry point. I have a launcher and this was always a good entry-point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [stated](https://plus.google.com/105051985738280261832/posts/4x9tJoFWNof) by Dianne Hackborn:

> ACTION_ASSIST is deprecated, though if you turn off the new assistant you can select an old ACTION_ASSIST assistant to use instead (and then also get to select an old voice recognizer).﻿

You can choose a custom application, instead Google Now, here:

```
Settings -> Apps -> Default Apps -> Assist & voice input -> Assist app
```