# Open Google Now on Tap without pressing home button

Tags: android, google-now

Is there a way I can open Now on Tap in my app without the user having to long press the home button? Feels like there should be an intent or something for this, but I can't find it.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33422213/action-assist-intent-on-marshmallow-android-6-0

Answer (score 0):

It would most likely be the same way you would open another activity in your app.
Take a look at [this page by Google](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html)